# django, debug=True -> real database error not shown but current transaction aborted

Tags: python, django

With django 1.5.4 :

When I'm using `DEBUG=False` in my settings.py then my "real" database errors are shown in console output for instance, example I just got:

```
DatabaseError: column "civility" of relation "customer_customer" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "customer_customer" ("site_id", "civility", "las...
```

But, when I'm on dev, I so use DEBUG=True but then the above error is not shown *nowhere* but instead a not really usefull one:

```
InternalError at /xxx
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

can't the "normal" error be "normally" propagated with DEBUG=True (I'm using debug_toolbar by the way) ??

thx for any advice.

--- SOLVED :

Ok I found the probably good fix. I added 'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': True,} to my DATABASES config. Now the error is shown on console with DEBUG activated or not. Now I have to think if this autocommit is what I want.. I guess yes.

Comment: just curious have you set your available host in the settings.py file?

Comment: well, yes, I guess you mean the ALLOWED_HOSTS list/tuple config parameter ? Actually (on dev machine) I've set it to ['*']. But I'm unsure if this is linked to this problem.

Comment: yeah I guess not.  I'm not sure I've ever seen sql errors show up with Debug set to false.  that is really unusual.

Comment: Ok I found the probably good fix. I added 'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': True,} to my DATABASES config. Now the error is shown on console with DEBUG activated or not. Now I have to think if this autocommit is what I want..

Comment: Rather than edit SOLVED into your title, you can answer your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the probably good fix. I added 'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': True,} to my DATABASES config. Now the error is shown on console with DEBUG activated or not. 
Now I have to think if this autocommit is what I want.. I guess yes.